# Use custom header as WordPress header

Tags: customization, headers

My site is running on site say : www.xyz.com
My blog is at say : http://www.xyz.com/blog

I have one header implemented in my main site, I want to use that header file as a worpress header. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Are you saying your blog is a WordPress site and you want it to have the same header as your main site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reproduce your site's header on the header.php file on your theme. If you want any more help you could show us some code. But basically that's it, WordPress gets the header for the page from the header.php on your theme. Check out say Twenty Ten's header as an example (wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php), and try to adapt your site's header to this format.